# Using optimized exists() for a set

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to add a property to my `Person` class that returns a boolean whether the person has a certain `AntecedentTag` or not.

For information, my simplified models go below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    antecedent_tags = models.ManyToManyField(AntecedentTag, verbose_name=u"Tags", through='AntecedentInfo')

class AntecedentInfo(models.Model):
    antecedent_tag = models.ForeignKey(AntecedentTag)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class AntecedentTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="64")
```

In my Person class, I was thinking of adding a `@property` like the below. It works, but if I have to use this on a list of let's say 250 individual persons, I'm afraid performance wise this is not going to be the best.

```
@property
def is_diabetic(self):
    try:
        if self.antecedentinfo_set.get(antecedent_tag__name="Diabetes"):
            return True
    except:
        return False
```

**Question**: is there any way to use the optimized `exists()` on a `set`?

I tried the below without success:

```
>>> p.antecedentinfo_set.get(antecedent_tag__name="Diabetes")
<AntecedentInfo: Diabetes: >
>>> p.antecedentinfo_set.get(antecedent_tag__name="Diabetes").exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'AntecedentInfo' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

I thought of `count()`, but that will not work if the Person doesn't have the disease:

```
>>> p.antecedentinfo_set.get(antecedent_tag__name="Diabetes")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xx\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "xx\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: AntecedentInfo matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists()` is a method of the queryset, not of the model instance.  So you need to call `filter()` instead of `get()`.

And why do you use the `antecedentinfo_set` intermediate relation?  Use the M2M field:

```
@property
def is_diabetic(self):
    return self.antecedent_tags.filter(name="Diabetes").exists()
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but it did not yield the right results. Turned out my test DB had a Tag Diabetes with `live` set to `False`, i.e. deleted. Hence it didn't show up. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

> In my Person class, I was thinking of adding a `@property` like the
>   below. It works, but if I have to use this on a list of let's say 250
>   individual persons, I'm afraid performance wise this is not going to
>   be the best.

I can think of two approaches that can save you from counting 250 times for a set of 250 persons.

#### 1. Using `.extra`

I will suppose that you don't have any custom Managers/QuerySets yet, for a maximum DRY-ness of the code it will be better to place the next lines of code into a custom Manager/QuerySet *(It will be still fine to write it into the View, but if you want to reuse this functionality somewhere else you will have to repeat it.)*.

So we are going to create a custom QuerySet class. If the topic is unfamiliar to you you can read more at [Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#managers)

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    #this adds a new field "has_"+disease 
    #for every object in our queryset
    def annotate_disease_existence(self, disease):
        has_disease = 'has_'+disease
        return self.extra(select={
            has_disease: "SELECT count(*) \
                FROM someapp_antecedentinfo \
                LEFT JOIN someapp_antecedenttag \
                    ON someapp_antecedenttag.id = someapp_antecedentinfo.antecedent_tag_id
                WHERE someapp_antecedentinfo.person_id = someapp_person.id \
                    AND someapp_antecedenttag.name = '%s" % disease
        })

#now lets use it
class Person(models.Model):
    #...    
    objects = PersonQuerySet.as_manager()
```

**How to use it?**

This custom method we wrote gives us the ability to call it against every `Person` QuerySet. So we can do:

```
def my_special_view(request):
    my250persons = Person.objects.annotate_disease_existence("Diabetes")[:250]

    for person in my250persons:
        print "{} has Diabetes? {}".format(
            person, 
            'Yes' if person.has_diabetes else 'No'
        )
```

#### 2. Using `.prefetch_related`

I hope you already saw what we did in the first example - we used a `subquery` add an extra bit of information to the `Person` if he has some illness or not. But a problem arrives when we actually want to use the whole Disease *(Tag or Info in our case)* objects. Then we can use `prefetch_related` with custom `Prefetch` object.

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def prefetch_disease(self, disease):
        disease_set = disease.lower() + '_set'
        return self.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            #depending on our needs
            'antecedent_tags', # OR 'antecedentinfo_set'
            queryset = AntecedentTag.objects.filter(name=disease),
            #OR queryset = AntecedentInfo.objects.filter(antecedent_tag__name=disease)
            to_attr = disease_set
        ))
```

**How to use?**

When using this approach we are adding a new list of objects to every `Person` of our `queryset`. So we can access them like so:

```
def my_very_special_view(request):
    my250persons = Person.objects.prefetch_disease("Diabetes")[:250]

    for person in my250persons:
        print "{} has Diabetes? {}! More Info: {}".format(
            person, 
            'Yes' if person.diabetes_set else 'No',
            person.diabetes_set[0]
        )
```

#### OK it works, but how to use it with single object?

```
def my_single_person_view(request, id):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person.objects.prefetch_disease("Diabetes"),pk=id)
    #or
    person = get_object_or_404(Person.objects.annotate_disease_existence("Diabetes"),pk=id)
```